# Limits of JVM JIT-Compiler Optimizations

Tags: java, optimization, jvm, compiler-optimization, jit

I am currently working on a compiler from a custom DSL to Java while performing some rudementary performance optimizations in the process. My biggest problem is that there are no academic resources to be found about what JIT-Compilers will do in regards to optimization (passes) or to what extend they will do it (e.g. complex dead-code-elimination, see example below). There are many blog posts saying JIT-Compilers won't do all the optimizations an AOT-Compiler would do because of certain time-constraints, but none mentions what this actually means. Is there a general rule of thumb ? Do I need to dive into e.g. the OpenJDK C++ source to understand this? Is there any research about this? And if there isn't, is there are least a credible ressource about what kind of optimizations the JVM JIT does ? The latest resources I have found are about Java 5, which is quite outdated (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/5-136747.html)

Here is a simplified example of a ,,complex dead-code elimination" scenario which I have found the JVM JIT not to be able to eliminate, given the Variable cells_S_S_S is not used anywhere (bear in mind this is auto-generated code):

```
List<List<List<Cell>>> cells_S_S_S = new ArrayList<>(pla_S.size());
...
for (int pla_S_itr_45 = 0; pla_S_itr_45 < pla_S_size_45; ++pla_S_itr_45) {
        ...
        List<List<Cell>> cells_S_S = new ArrayList<>(tmpVarIf20_S.size());
        for (int tmpVarIf20_S_itr_44 = 0; tmpVarIf20_S_itr_44 < tmpVarIf20_S_size_44; ++tmpVarIf20_S_itr_44) {
            ...
            List<Cell> cells_S = _state.getCells();
            ...
            cells_S_S.add(cells_S);
        }
        ...
        cells_S_S_S.add(cells_S_S);
    }
```

This sort of ,,nested dead-code" was not eliminated which had me perform said optimizations on my own.

In short: I want to know what the JVM JIT is capable of so that I can focus my own optimization passes on the right areas.

Comment: Perhaps this link is interesting: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTacticIndex (the wiki site is loading very slowly today, so you might use archiving sites).

Comment: Thanks for your input! Sadly this isn't helping me at all, as there is no exact information nor any references on that page. It's just a huge black box as it seems.

Comment: Though the question is interesting, it is off-topic on Stack Overflow, since it is too broad and/or asks for an off-site resource.

Comment: This question is about what JIT-Compilers actually do. How is this to broad? The other part of my question is just to give context / examples. I understand your remark about off-site resources though.

Comment: Well, is the topic discussed on every major Java conference for more than 10 years already, broad? Okay, if you want a short answer - start with [this page](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTechniques). It also links to many related topics. Then you might want to look at presentations from [JVM Language Summit](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/mlvm/jvmlangsummit/) (all years).

Comment: The general advice, to be perfectly frank, is to trust the JIT to know what it's doing better than you do and to only make performance-focused changes based on actual time measurements rather than trying to predict what the JIT will do.  The JIT is a black box.  Don't hope to understand it.

Comment: The first linked page doesn't contain any detailed information but a link to a presentation which doesn't really provide its information resources (a general link to jvmsummit isn't enough of a base). All in all there are no credible resources about this topic. I don't want to belittle the jvm language summit talks and slides but they don't provide quality information sources which brings me back to my original problem: there is much information about what the JVM JIT does but not to what extent plus there is no info about what it doesn't do compared to an AOT compiler.

Comment: @LouisWasserman this isn't about prediction or some sort of micro-optimization. Telling me to stop trying to understand it is not helpful at all either. I am writing a compiler so how am I supposed to make performance-focused changes for generic programs without running them? I am not talking about case-specific optimizations. I want to know broad areas where JIT Compilers are lacking which frankly seems to be undocumented.

Comment: You aren't _supposed_ to "make performance-focused changes," basically, is the design philosophy of the JVM.  The expectation is that the code being passed to the JVM is completely unoptimized.

Comment: What about specific optimizations in regards to my own DSL which the JVM JIT cannot know of because it can't guarantee certain conditions ? Should I not do that kind of optimization on my own ? And how do I know if the JVM JIT cant guarantee said conditions? I don't want to profile enormous amounts of cases and check the generated assembly myself, but it seems thats the only way I can get any information about this topic. Edit: @LouisWasserman, thanks for your time. I appreciate it

Comment: Additionally the given example in my question (slightly modified) is an exact case where the JVM JIT does not handle unoptimized code well

Comment: E.g. I saw one-hour 100-slides presentations devoted to a single optimization like scalar replacement. How do you imagine an answer suitable for SO format that covers all JIT optimizations in details?

Comment: I'd be glad to help you if you were more specific. For instance, it is easy to explain why your sample code is not dead from HotSpot JVM viewpoint. Array allocations with non-constant size are not subject to scalar replacement. Any heap allocation (i.e. not replaced/eliminated) potentially has side effects (GC). The code with side effects is not considered "dead".

Comment: I don't expect an SO format post to answer all JIT optimizations in detail. I am looking for resources and some basic explanation to which extent some optimizations are made and even what kind of optimizations are done, but in greater detail than what one would find in presentations. The only complex optimization that is explained in great detail ís inlining of monomorphic and bi-morphic call sites. The biggest black box, at least for me, is what the time restrictions of the JIT  in regards to optimiziation actually mean, non-superficial but in detail. The point is, there are no good resources

Comment: I see only 1 way: generate the Assembly and see what comes out of it. Keep in mind that the generated Assembly might change in a different version; so what might be true today, might not be true tomorrow.

Comment: @apangin Do you have any references / links to back up your statement about "Any heap allocation (i.e. not replaced/eliminated) potentially has side effects (GC)" ? What about escape analysis etc. ? I think that there is enough information to DCE If all list methods are inlined aggressively.

Comment: Escape Analysis helps to *eliminate* heap allocation. My statement was about *actual allocation* in the heap (i.e. not eliminated). I've told why allocation of ArrayList is not eliminated in your case - because it contains an array of non-constant size. See [escape.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/567e410935e5/src/share/vm/opto/escape.cpp#l789)

Comment: @apangin I appreciate your effot, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know what the JVM JIT is capable of so that I can focus my own optimization passes on the right areas.

Simple answer: Don't.

You have to consider two things:

1. Yes, the Oracle HotSpot JVM JIT engine performs a wide range of optimisations during multiple passes. Some of those you listed (dead-code elimination, inlining, de-virtualization, etc...) and many more.
   It's important to note that the behaviour of the JIT Engine is not
   standardized and JVMs from other company behave in different ways. I've never seen a document describing comprehensively how HotSpot takes its decisions internally or the list of optimizations supported and I highly doubt such document exists (not from Oracle, not from the community). You could dive into the source of the HotSpot VM, but:
2. HotSpot continuously tries to determine *hot spots* in your application and in a non-deterministic way decide what needs to be jitted, how to do it in the current context(for hotter methods it makes sense to apply costly optimizations) and which jitted methods need to be discarded and possibly recompiled.
   The state of your application is not stable, and the JIT engine constantly decide what to do with it and choses which set of optimizations will be applied depending on the current environment.

You are trying to optimize the code that you are transpiling from your DSL for a specific JIT behaviour, but every assumption you are making could be valid for one specific run but not for another. Or not being valid anymore after a while, when the jit engine decides to drop the jitted version of your method to free memory or to compile it again with different results.

The only difference between JIT and AOT is that for the latter there are *no* time constraints, so you try to produce the best code you can, for some measure of quality.

Comment: I see your point about the non-determinism of the JIT. But as it stands I am more than suprised that there isn't any scientific research / paper about this at all, not even for a specific Java version / OpenJDK version. Also I don't want to optimize for the JIT to produce better code, but optimize parts of my program which a JIT inherently can't optimize (See comment chain on the main post about why the JIT can't ,,dead-code-optimize" my example) but this seems like a more general optimization problem even AOT-Compilers would run into.

Comment: I agree, I searched for that kind of documentation years ago and couldn't find anything comprehensive, the most interesting bits about details of the JIT were scattered around a multitude of blogs and articles. My guess is that considering the low volume of contributors (mainly on the runtime) they never felt the need to make public document describing the internal design and the choices they made in the past.

Answer (score 0):

JIT Optimization is actually far more powerful than Whole-Program optimization. JIT Optimization adapts the code temporarily for the best performance and makes extremely unsafe optimizations based on assumptions about the code. For example, the JIT optimizer can precompute something and then rolls it back if the assumption turns wrong. The JIT inliner helps the JIT optimizer by inlining methods so they can be adapted to their specific caller.